# "unbound method must be called with instance as first argument ( got something else instead)"

Tags: python

so i've been working on a little asteroids game and i have the following problem:

in my main file I create an instance Ship (inherits from GameObject) and pass it to my EntitySystem. But when I try to update the EntitySystem i get the error "unbound method must be called with ship instance as first argument ( got float variable instead)" - none of the answers on similar questions on the web really helped me :| any ideas?

Simplified code:

```
class Game:

    def main(self):
        global ship
        ship = Ship(100,100)

        entities = EntitySystem()
        entities.addEntity("ship", Ship)

        # MAIN LOOP_________________________________
        while True:
            #do shomething

            #update engine
            entities.update()

class GameObject:

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.pos=[x, y]


    def update():
        pass


class Ship(GameObject):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        GameObject.__init__(self,x,y)


    def update(self, time):    
        # do something

class EntitySystem():

    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.currentEntities = []

    def update(self):
        for cEnt in self.currentEntities:
           cEnt.update(global_variables.DELTA_TIME)

    def addEntity(self, name, newEntity):
        self.currentEntities.insert(self.index,newEntity)
        self.index = self.index + 1
```

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: I believe you want to call `entities.addEntity("ship", ship)` instead of `entities.addEntity("ship", Ship)`.  However, you should paste the complete error message to be sure people understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Andalso, you forgot a `self` in `class GameObject: ... def update(*)`.

Comment: You are adding the Ship class to entity system and not the instance `ship`. Some remarks to the code: Why is `ship` global? `index` in `EntitySystem` is not necessary, lists have the append-method to add items to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems:

- In your main, you want to pass `ship` (the variable) in parameter and not `Ship` (the class)
- You forgot the first argument `self` in `GameObject.self`
- `ship` shouldn't be global here, it's useless (at least in this portion of code). Avoid using global variables in general anyway if possible